# How to view individual gold in the new spectator UI?

Tags: league-of-legends

In the old spectator UI you could view each champion's current gold and total gold earned by clicking the gold bag at the top of the champion scoreboard.

With the new UI you can bring up the champion scoreboard by holding "tab" but the individual champion gold button is no longer there.

Is there some other way to access this information or has this feature been removed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the spectator menu, while holding "tab" or pressing "h" to keep the HUD up, press the "x" key to display character total gold and current gold.

An example of what that looks like is included below.
[image]

Comment: The number on the left is how much gold they're holding onto. The number in parentheses on the right is their total gold.